# Decode string with plus sign

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, urlencode, asp.net-routing, asp.net-core-3.1

Using ASP.NET Core I am receiving the following token (simplified):

```cs
String token = "Z%2F3+3Q==";
```

The `/` is encoded using `%2F`. I received the token from a URL called on the client using Angular.

I tried to decode the token using the following:

```cs
HttpUtility.UrlDecode(token)
```

Or

```cs
WebUtility.UrlDecode(token)
```

In both cases `%2F` is replaced by `/`, which I want, but the `+` is replaced by a space, which I do not want.

How do I decode the string?

**Update**

The client application is sending the token encoded:

```cs
Z%2F3%2B3Q%3D%3D;
```

But, somehow, it seems the token in the following action:

```cs
[HttpPut("account/verify/{userId}/{token}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> VerityEmailAddress([FromRoute]AccountEmailVerifyModel model) {
}
```

Is transformed to:

```cs
Z%2F3+3Q==
```

So the `+` and `=` are decoded, but the `/` is not.

Comment: If you want the end result to include the plus-sign, the sending application will need to escape it properly.  If you can't change the sending tool, then you may need to do it yourself before calling UrlDecode(...).

Comment: Try URL-encoding a string that looks like `"this/that+other space"`.  The result will be `"this%2fthat%2bother+space"`.  The space gets encoded at `+` and the plus sign as `%2b`

Comment: @RLH The client application is encoding correctly the `+`, the `=` and the `/`. But somehow the model binder decodes everything but not the `/`. I added an update to my question.

Comment: What does the original token supposed to be?

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ The original token should be `Z/3+3Q==` ... And it is a token generated by ASP.NET Core Identity to verify an email address.

Comment: @MiguelMoura ok I may have something shortly.

Comment: @MiguelMoura the actual reason for the problem is the actual encoded token, the `+` should be `%2B`, the token is malformed. This worked for me `HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(token), Encoding.UTF8).Replace(" ", "+");` You can also confirm by having your token to `Z%2F3%2B3Q==` and then do `HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(token), Encoding.UTF8)` without the replace and it works just fine.

Comment: My comment above is based on the main issue you were having with `Z%2F3+3Q==`

Comment: since normally a + should be encoded as %2B it is strange that that is not how it's being sent to you... but if the plus sign is an exception with whatever encoding then you must handle the + sign separately: either replacing space with + afterwards as @Çöđěxěŕ mentioned or by replacing + with the correct "%2B" code before you put it through the decode function.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The key here is that this is being passed as a *route parameter* and the specific character that’s not being properly decoded is a `/`. As you might imagine, there's some potential problems when dealing with a `/` in route parameters, since they're normally treated as route delimiters.

#### Background

Ultimately, *this is a known limitation* with both the **ASP.NET MVC Framework** and now **ASP.NET Core**. There are quite a few discussions about this on the [ASP.NET GitHub site](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/). On [#4599](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4599) (from 2016), there's a lengthy debate about whether or not this is the *correct* behavior. On [#4445](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/4445) (from 2019), a contributor from Microsoft committed to [providing an option to allow decoding of these parameters](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/11544#issuecomment-506802681).

Unfortunately, however, this didn't make it into either **ASP.NET Core 3.1** or **ASP.NET Core 5.0**—and while it remains open, it has been demoted from a **PRI: 1 - Required** issue to a **severity-minor** issue.

#### Workaround

Until Microsoft provides a solution to this, there are three options for working around the behavior:

1. Pass the `{token}` parameter via the query string instead, where it will be fully decoded.
2. Add code to your application that explicitly decodes the `%2F` *after* binding has occurred.
3. Create your own `IModelBinder` to modify the model binding behavior itself.

> **Update:** Contributor @Celluj34 has provided [a sample implementation of a custom model binder](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/11544#issuecomment-958111390) to solve this on [the GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/11544).

None of these are especially satisfying. But this at least confirms that the behavior you're seeing is known and expected, even if it's arguably incorrect.

Comment: I faced the same issue, read all articles. What it means is **never use route segment strings that can take any value/character**. If you want to accept any value, use FromQuery or other type of string. Microsoft won't change this as they consider it normal (at least consistent) behavior. May it is.